# Security - Die or replace on invalid value for include

Tags: php, security, include

I would like to know which of the following solutions is more secure.

```
if(!ctype_alpha($_GET['a'])){
    //another string can be put here if necessary
    die('No Hacking!');
}
```

or

```
if(!ctype_alpha($_GET['a'])){
    //Changed for security in depth, in-case I accidently use $_GET['a'] elsewhere. Designed to simulate header('Location: ./?a=default_value');
    $_GET['a'] = 'default_value';
}
```

something similar to the following happens later in the script:

```
//make_safe is defined elsewhere, it is security in depth (redundancy) to remove slashes if they get past ctype_alpha using some unknown bug
$var = make_safe($_GET['a']);
require_once("./data/include/$var.php");
```

In a book I am currently reading, it says that it is best to stop all input not following my rules, instead of correcting. Therefore, my question boils down to does replacing the $_GET['a'] with a default parameter count as stopping the input, or must die() be used?

Comment: What do you want to show to your user?

Comment: There are plenty of `HTTP` status codes for that. Just respond with `HTTP 400` and show some error page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Die('fu')` is a dirty thing.

I prefer your way of sanitizing inputs with default values if needed.

By the way, that's what does major companies (check at google, search something, go to page 2, now change `start` parameter in the url to something not numeric, you'll be back to page 1).

Plus, when hacking stuff, you'll try to have the application acting in a singular way.

If yours acts always the same, it's very frustrating for hackers, they'll hopefully feel bored quite quickly.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will wait before marking it as accepted though because I need to see if one with more explanation comes along, better than 'I prefer...' without any substantial because.